# Android Compatibility : SDK, NDK, manufacturer specific SDK - Confused Beyond Sanity

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, compatibility

I am new to software development and have been working on Android for past few months. I just published an epic failure of an application which was highly disheartening.

Now what went wrong in my app was compatibility. It worked perfectly on the devices I tested it on and developed for. But soon I came to know about layout issues, app crashing on different phones and that too due to different reasons on different phones.
So even after months of development I am back to being a noob when it comes to Android development.
Now to get you into my perspective I would like to share what my app was about and what were some of the issues I faced:

**Application**: A simple call recording and blocking application which used classes like MediaRecorder, ITelephony(through Java Reflections).

So some of the issues I faced were:

1. MediaRecorder would start recording calls after 5-10 seconds on some phones, thus,  resulting in 10 seconds shorter recording.
2. On certain phones(Samsung Galaxy S3 for one) my layout was destroyed. I had a PopUpWindow on click of image which is perfect on all phones except on this one where popup decreases to 1/4th of it's intended width.
3. My button size would differ on some phones(same sized but different manufacturers so they must be using same layout file.)
4. **NoSuchMethod** on some phones(Android V4.1.2 and V4.3) when using ***ContentProvider for finding Contacts*** name and Image.

So I wanted to get answers to few questions that I don't seem to get cleared out of my head.

1. What the hell went wrong in my case.
2. Do I need to download manufacturer specific SDKs for my app. Like Samsung SDK for Samsung phones, HTC SDK for HTC. If not then what do these SDKs do.

   2.1 Are they only for device specific features.
3. Do I need to even read about NDK. I only know Java as of now.
4. What are the common mistakes considering:

   4.1 Compatibility across devices.

   4.2 Compatibility across Android versions.

So answer these questions if they are even remotely relevant when it comes to compatibility. Please answer as many questions as you can.

**or is this the only answer**: Test your app in 40 different phones. Period.

**EDIT:** I used a Popupwindow like this :

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().from(this).inflate(R.layout.corner_dialog, null);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        switch(metrics.densityDpi){
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            popUp.setWidth(155);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            popUp.setWidth(200);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            popUp.setWidth(305);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            popUp.setWidth(400);
            break;
        }
        popUp.setContentView(v);
        popUp.setHeight(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popUp.showAsDropDown(view);
```

Comment: Questions like, "what are all the possible things that could go wrong" aren't really appropriate for stackoverflow -- that's more blog post territory.  Your first item, "what the hell went wrong", is entirely appropriate, but you need to provide more details.  For example, when you say "same sized" phone, what were the display resolutions and pixel densities of each?  It's likely they used different layouts because they had different physical characteristics.  There is no manufacturer-specific SDK requirement.

Comment: Same sized - Layout was correct on 540 x 960 pixels, 4.5 inches (~245 ppi pixel density) but went wrong on 720 x 1280 pixels, 4.8 inches (~306 ppi pixel density). Is that too much of a difference? Also I have added some details in my question.